# Some solution for a particular system of non-linear equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have come across this system of equations where $q>1$ is a real constant, $x_i$ and $y_i$ are real variables and $y_i>0$:

$$
\begin{align}
  1~~   & = x_0 ~~~~ ~~+ x_1 ~~~~~~~+ x_2                          \\
  q~~   & = x_0 y_0 ~~+ x_1 y_1 ~~~+ x_2 y_2              \\
  q~~   & = x_0 y_0^{-1} + x_1 y_1^{-1} + x_2 y_2^{-1} \\
  q^4 & = x_0 y_0^2 ~~+ x_1 y_1^2 ~~~+ x_2 y_2^2        \\
  q^4 & = x_0 y_0^{-2}+ x_1 y_1^{-2} + x_2 y_2^{-2} \\
\end{align}
$$

or equivalently

$$
\begin{align}
  q~~ &= y_0 + x_1 (y_1 - y_0) + x_2 (y_2 - y_0) \\
  q^4 &= y_0^2 + x_1 (y_1^2 - y_0^2) + x_2 (y_2^2 - y_0^2) \\
  q \cdot y_0 y_1 y_2 &= y_1 y_2 + x_1 y_2 (y_0 -y_1) + x_2 y_1 (y_0 -
  y_2) \\
  q^{4} \cdot (y_0 y_1 y_2)^2 &= (y_1 y_2)^2 + x_1 y_2^2 (y_0^2 -y_1^2) + x_2 y_1^2 (y_0^2 - y_2^2)
\end{align}
$$

I am interested in finding a solution to the equations. Any ideas?

Comment: I hope that you noticed that you show five equations for six unknowns.

Comment: Indeed, and I was hoping that this would increase my chance to find some solution.